# Looping through firebase unique keys and adding data to each

Tags: firebase

I have firebase database in this form.

```
"items":{
  "-Jp9VLYBwENfNVLKYyCG" : {
    "-Jp9VMKkTUggcMrUCO8S" : {
      "author" : "facebook:#########",
      "created" : 1431474107638,
    },
    "-Jp9VobJP0qbSbbEdyW0" : {
      "author" : "facebook:#########",
      "created" : 1431474227548
    }
  },
  "-JpEbifKeRj-_H7TWhQ2" : {
    "-JpEbrnT6SFRFc6U_HWX" : {
      "author" : "facebook:#########",
      "created" : 1431559961683
    },
    "-JpEby5mZuQMsU-9YCpk" : {
      "author" : "facebook:##########",
      "created" : 1431559987495
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add the following object to each $id containing author and created key-value pairs.

```
upVote: {
  active: true,
  total: 0
},
downVote: {
  active: true,
  total: 0
}
```

I am first trying to fetch the values using DataSnapshot. But it doesn't print the keys in console. What is wrong here?

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + "/items");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("snapshot key: " + snapshot.key());
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
    var key = childSnapshot.key();
    var val = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log("child snapshot key: " + key);
    childSnapshot.forEach(function(deepSnap){
      console.log("deep shot key: " + deepSnap.key());
    });
  });
});
```

**RESOLVED** The problem was that I had some security rules set up with read and write permissions. Therefore wasn't allowing me to read the element from the user scope that I was calling the script. It was one gotcha like problems.
After this step, it was easy to update the database with values:

```
var deepRef = ref.child(key).child(deepSnap.key());
deepRef.update({upVote: {
                            active: true,
                            total: 0
                        },downVote: {
                            active: true,
                            total: 0
                        }});
```

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `console.log(snapshot.val())`?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/wiriho/edit?js,console